# Inner join on the same row twice

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

games:

```
id | tournament | player1 | player 2
1  | 1          | 1       | 2
2  | 1          | 3       | 4
```

players

```
id | name
1  | Johnson
2  | Smith
```

tournaments

```
id | name
1  | Tournament 1
```

Now I want to extract all information in the table 'games'.
I've used:

```
SELECT t.name, g.player1, g.player2
FROM tournaments AS t
INNER JOIN games AS g ON g.tournament = t.id
```

This works for extracting the information for the tournament - but I'm looking for the same for the players as well. The only solution I could find was after my loop to do another SQL to extract the information from the player:

```
 SELECT * FROM players where id = player1variable
```

Is this the best solution? Is it possible to include this information in the first SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by JOINing to the `players` table twice, once for each player:

```
SELECT t.name, p1.*, p2.*
FROM tournaments AS t
INNER JOIN games AS g ON g.tournament = t.id
INNER JOIN players AS p1 ON p1.id = g.player1
INNER JOIN players AS p2 ON p2.id = g.player2
```

Output:

```
name            id  name    id  name
Tournament 1    1   Johnson 2   Smith
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRUP5rih95gacrzSubZM73/0)

Note that this will give you columns with the same name, which may cause issues in your application. You can work around this by using column aliases:

```
SELECT t.name, p1.name AS player1, p2.name AS player2
FROM tournaments AS t
INNER JOIN games AS g ON g.tournament = t.id
INNER JOIN players AS p1 ON p1.id = g.player1
INNER JOIN players AS p2 ON p2.id = g.player2
```

Output:

```
name            player1     player2
Tournament 1    Johnson     Smith
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sRUP5rih95gacrzSubZM73/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use SubQuery.

```
SELECT t.name
  , g.player1
  , (select m.name from players m where m.id = g.player1) as player1_name
  , g.player2
  , (select m.name from players m where m.id = g.player2) as player2_name
FROM tournaments AS t
INNER JOIN games AS g ON g.tournament = t.id
```